# Dynamically Controlled Observable Interval

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

On my website I have a global drop down called "Auto Refresh" that lets you select a poll interval: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. and when selected it will cause the HTTP APIs of the current page to be polled every 0, 1, 2, 3 seconds, etc.

I've have this so far:

```
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    private interval: number = 0;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    autoRefreshObservable() {
        if (this.interval > 0)
            return Observable.timer(this.interval * 1000);

        return Observable.timer(999999999999999);
    }

    getApi(url: string) {
        return Observable.of(null)
                .switchMap(e => this.autoRefreshObservable())
                .flatMap(() => this.http.get(url))
                .repeat();
    }

    updateInterval(i: number) {
        this.interval = i;
    }
}
```

And if I call something like `this.apiService.getApi("/api/foo").subscribe(response => {...})` in a component, it works... sort of. If you ever set auto-refresh to 0, it will never work again until you refresh the page. Also, I want it to return the first response immediately, but then wait the interval for subsequent responses.

Is this even possible to do from within the service? Or do I have to move this logic into the components using it?

The thing is, there are a lot of components, and adding auto-refresh support to each and every one is going to require a lot of boilerplate; that's why I was hoping to move the logic to a shared service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your duration is changing over time so we can make the interval as an observable by using `BehaviourSubject`. Having said this, let's update the `ApiService` like this -

```
    export class ApiService {    

    interval$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

    getApi(url: string) {

        return this.interval$
                   .pipe(
                       switchMap(duration => {

                            //From your current code (Observable.timer(999999999999999);), it appears that on duration 0
                            //You do not want to call API; So this check will take care of that
                            if (duration === 0) {
                                //lets not emit anything; i.e. wait for the a NON zero duration
                                return NEVER;
                            }

                           return interval(duration * 1000)
                                  .pipe(
                                      switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))                                      
                                  );
                       })
                   );
    }

    updateInterval(i: number) {
        this.interval$.next(i);
    }
}
```

See the working example [just a simulation] - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pi3uaz?file=app%2Fapi.service.ts

Hope it gives an idea to resolve your issue.

Comment: You can just use a `Subject` instead of a `BehaviourSubject`, so that the dirty `duration` checking code can be removed. Alternatively you can do `.skip(1)` to skip the first emission of value 0

Comment: @CozyAzure I am not sure why you are saying a `duration` check dirty. OP needs to stop the API call once the user selects '0' from the dropdown; so `skip(1)` is of no use; although I see we can skip first '0' but we need `if` in some form. Of course, you can use `iif` operator like this -  `iif(() => duration === 0, NEVER, obs);` if you are not liking `if` check but conceptually it is also the same thing. Bottom line is OP needs to stop calling the API once '0' is selected and start again if other than '0' is selected.

Comment: This answer has been immensely helpful, I've posted my solution (with modifications) below

Comment: One question, though - is `pipe()` really needed even if it is only taking 1 parameter?

Comment: @Gillespie I did not understand what you mean by if “it is only taking 1 parameter” but ‘.pipe()’ is needed in rxjs 6 if you want to process the output of an observable and it does not matter if you use one operator or many operators in observable pipeline.

Comment: Ah, I'm not on rxjs 6 yet, I suppose I should do it in case we upgrade

Comment: @Gillespie basically pipe was introduced in rxjs 5.5. Looks like you are using <5.5 version. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Answer (score 1):

With a few modifications to @user2216584's answer, I got it to do exactly what I wanted:

```
getApi(url: string) {
    return this.interval$
    .pipe(
        switchMap(duration => {
            if (duration === 0)
                return this.http.get(url);

            return interval(duration * 1000).startWith(0).pipe(
                switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
            );
        })
    );
}
```